# Invoking a Google Cloud Function with non-http trigger via python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a cloud function (1st gen) with a trigger when a new object is created in a bucket

```
gcloud functions deploy <function_name> \
    --source <source_folder> \
    --trigger-bucket=<trigger_bucket> \
    --region europe-west3 \
    --runtime python38 \
    ...
```

It is possible to manually test it by using `gcloud`

```
gcloud functions call <function_name> --data '{"bucket": "<trigger_bucket>", "name": "<file_name>"}'
```

However, I'd also like this cloud function on some past files (not all of them) in the bucket.

So I tried to write a python script

```py
from google.auth.request import Request
from google.oauth2
import requests

cloud_function_url = "https://europe-west3-<project_name>.cloudfunctions.net/<function_name>"
token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), cloud_function_url)

def invoke_cloud_function():
    return requests.post(cloud_function_url, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}, json={"bucket": "<trigger_bucket>", "name": "<file_name>"})
```

I am however getting an error 401 `'\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<title>401 Unauthorized</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/dev_ingestion_collection</code>.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n'`

I seems that the issue stems from the trigger not be an http trigger, because the same code but using the `trigger-http` seems to work.

However, the gcloud command seems to hint that there is the possibility to run an HTTP request to trigger a non-HTTP cloud fonction, even though I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Is there any way to do this other than using `subprocess.run("gcloud functions call ...") ?

Comment: Have you tried enabling **Allow unauthenticated invocations** in the **Authentication** section in the **Trigger** panel? You can also add the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag when you deploy your function. Take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation).

Comment: This does not work, even though I can deploy a bucket-triggered function with the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag, I am still getting the same 401 error.
Additionally, I would not be comfortable for this cloud function to be triggered by anyone on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http#deployment).

> (1st gen) The --security-level flag controls whether the function endpoint requires HTTPS. The value secure-always means HTTPS is required and non-SSL HTTP requests are not supported. The value secure-optional means both HTTP and HTTPS are supported. The default is secure-always.

Since you're invoking your function using the `--trigger-bucket`(non HTTP trigger), you should set your `--security-level` to **secure-optional** because Cloud Function gen 1 is **secure-always** by default.

Also, try adding **https://** at the start of your Cloud Function link.  Both 1st and 2nd gen functions have assigned URLS that uses the following [format](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http#url):

```
https://REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME
```

Comment: My bad, the missing `https://` was indeed a typo